# IndexError: index 13 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 13 issue

Tags: python, nlp

I get this error:

> IndexError: index 13 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 13

but I can't seem to fix it. Can you please help me?

```
def sample_labels( y, num_of_sents = 5, num_of_samples = 10,
                      num_of_classes = 1, start_index = 5, get_prob = True):
    #Get a sense of how labels in y look like
    classes = classes_()
    ret = []
    x=list(y)

    for sent in x[:num_of_sents]:
        cur = []
        for word in sent[start_index: start_index + num_of_samples]:
            sorted_prob = am(word)
            print('sorted_prob',sorted_prob) 
            print ('sorted_prob len', len(sorted_prob)) 
            print('word',word)
            #print('cur',cur)
            print('number of classes',num_of_classes)
            cur.append([(classes[ind], word[ind]) if get_prob 
                        else classes[ind]
                        for ind in sorted_prob[:num_of_classes]]) #------ERROR here----------
            print('cur and end of inner 4 loop',cur)
            print('classesind',classes)

        ret.append(cur)
        print('cur',cur)
    return ret
```

Here is a sample of the printed statements

> sorted_prob [12, 13, 4, 2, 3, 0, 6, 1, 14, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 10]
>
> sorted_prob len 15
>
> word  [3.9363772e-06 6.2428586e-07 1.2910984e-05 4.0524797e-06
>   4.3209013e-05
>    2.4976660e-07 1.3571737e-06 1.0090356e-09 1.5341955e-11 4.4677283e-12
>    1.8482331e-15 1.6146554e-14 9.9985778e-01 7.5455580e-05 4.0608529e-07]
>
> number of classes 1
>
> cur and end of inner 4 loop [['P-I']]
>
> classesind ['A0-B' 'A0-I' 'A1-B' 'A1-I' 'A2-B' 'A2-I' 'A3-B' 'A3-I'
>   'A4-B' 'A4-I' 'O'  'P-B' 'P-I']
>
> sorted_prob [13, 12, 14, 1, 3, 0, 5, 4, 9, 2, 6, 7, 8, 11, 10]
>
> sorted_prob len 15
>
> word [1.40233034e-10 1.62562830e-09 1.44035496e-14 7.12817139e-10
>    2.15579486e-12 1.05151512e-11 2.58049413e-15 1.43085274e-15
>    1.61804985e-16 1.13536066e-13 4.95883708e-23 6.91257209e-19
>    1.88131162e-06 9.99998093e-01 7.41057393e-09]
>
> number of classes 1

Then error is thrown afterwards.

Comment: Python lists are indexed from zero, so the elements in a list of length 13 are indexed 0 - 12.  The first element of `sorted_prob` is `13`, so that will cause an `IndexError`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb ok since I am looping  in sorted_prob[:num_of_classes] and num_of_classes =1 so sorted_prob[:1] = 12,13 so the 12 index had no problem but  cur.append(classes[13]) classes[13] doesn't exist  so that's why error is thrown, thanks !!